# Is it possible for remote service to refer a member class instance from an Activity

Tags: android

I'm referring to this excellent tutorial [Android Architecture Tutorial: Developing an App with a Background Service (using IPC)](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/), which talks about running service in separate process.

In Remote Service, there is one method to remove listener passed from Activity.

### In Remote Service

```
@Override
public void removeListener(TweetCollectorListener listener) 
    throws RemoteException {

    synchronized (listeners) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

### In Activity

```
private TweetCollectorListener.Stub collectorListener = new TweetCollectorListener.Stub() {
    @Override
    public void handleTweetsUpdated() throws RemoteException {
        updateTweetView();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try {
        api.removeListener(collectorListener);
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // catch any issues, typical for destroy routines
        // even if we failed to destroy something, we need to continue destroying
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to unbind from the service", t);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Activity destroyed");
}
```

I doubt the `removeListener` will work correctly. I do a quick testing, by having the following code in remote service.

### In Remote Service

```
@Override
public void removeListener(TweetCollectorListener listener)
        throws RemoteException {

    synchronized (listeners) {
        Log.i("CHEOK", "before removing listner -> " + listeners.size());
        listeners.remove(listener);
        Log.i("CHEOK", "after removing listner -> " + listeners.size());
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following result.

```
before removing listner -> 1
after removing listner -> 1
```

My guess is that, even though Activity is passing the same instance of `TweetCollectorListener.Stub` during `addListener` and `removeListner`, but 2 different instances of `TweetCollectorListener` are being constructed at Service side `addListener` and `removeListner`.

I can further confirm this, by having the following log.

```
Activity calls service's addListener, by passing in com.mindtherobot.samples.tweetservice.TweetViewActivity$2@427c1190
In service's addListener, TweetCollectorListener is com.mindtherobot.samples.tweetservice.TweetCollectorListener$Stub$Proxy@427d68b0
Activity calls service's removeListener, by passing in com.mindtherobot.samples.tweetservice.TweetViewActivity$2@427c1190
In service's removeListener, TweetCollectorListener is com.mindtherobot.samples.tweetservice.TweetCollectorListener$Stub$Proxy@427d7188
```

**So, is there any way I can remove listener from remote service? Sometimes, I would like to remove an old listener, and attach with new listener.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the remote service, in order to compare the `TweetCollectorListener` objects, you need to use the underlying `Binder` object, as follows:

```
@Override
public void removeListener(TweetCollectorListener listener)
    throws RemoteException {

    synchronized (listeners) {
        Log.i("CHEOK", "before removing listner -> " + listeners.size());
        for (TweetCollectorListener tcl : listeners) {
            if (tcl.asBinder() == listener.asBinder()) {
                listeners.remove(tcl);
                break;
            }
        }
        Log.i("CHEOK", "after removing listner -> " + listeners.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Going to try it out.